# Google Maps API HTTP Restrictions: how to use wildcards?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-console-developer

Based on documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#adding_http_restrictions)

I added http restrictions using wildcards like so:

- https://*.mydomain.com
- https://*.mydomain.com/*

This should cover all paths for all subdomains, but I receive `RefererNotAllowedMapError` error when I try to use `https://www.dev.mydomain.com/#/`

I even tried explicitly adding `https://www.dev.mydomain.com/#/`, but I get same error.

I am totally lost and have no idea what to do. Clearly other people are using Google Maps APIs and not leaving them totally unrestricted so there has to be a way to do this.

Comment: What is the URL the error message indicates needs to be authorized?

Comment: `https://www.dev.mydomain.com/#/`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of a third-party service and not about programming.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding these two HTTP restrictions instead:

1. `*.mydomain.com/*`
2. `mydomain.com/*`

These two will allow your API key to be used in all sub-domains and paths in your website.

Adding (*.) before your domain  will allow something like "www.mydomain.com" or "dev.domain.com" to access your API key.

Adding (*) after your domain will allow something like "domain.com/path" to access your API key.

Comment: I wonder whether the trailing wildcard is required. In my tests, only having leading wildcards is enough; the API still works on `domain.com/path`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late for OP but adding this for posterity/future visitors. I don't think wildcards work for multi-level subdomains. In order to enable [www.dev.yourdomain.com](http://www.dev.yourdomain.com) you would need to either add it verbatim or use a wildcard to allow any subdomain of dev.yourdomain.com, i.e. `*.dev.yourdomain.com`